# How to Achieve Similar Animation in Flutter Like the Video

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I am trying to implement the animation in the video link below:

[Animation Video](https://imgur.com/a/4qewQ22)

The Icon that is being animated is a single **`SVG`** file with three arrows. The arrows are not separate images or icon assets.

So, What I tried to accomplish that is, I used **`flutter_svg`** and **`flutter_animate`** packages.

First of all, I added the **SVG** file and gave it the greenish color, and then added **shimmer** effect (did not get the expected outcome). Here is the code snippet.

```
SvgPicture.asset(
            'assets/icons/down_arrows.svg',
            height: 32.h,
            width: 32.h,
            colorFilter: const ColorFilter.mode(
              AppColors.bottomNavIconGreen,
              BlendMode.srcIn,
            ),
          )
              .animate(
                  onPlay: (controller) => controller.repeat(period: 3000.ms))
              .shimmer(
                color: AppColors.mainGreen,
                angle: 1.5,
              ),
```

Kindly help me achieve the animation like the video with this approach or any other way. Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Have you tried searching for Lottie files?

Comment: No, I haven't. The Figma design provides only the image formats. @PawanAcharya

Answer (score 1):

This kind of animation can be done in flutter but this needs few different components to work. I can think of an approach to draw canvas with arrows & animate the canvas.

**1. You need Animation tween to do this with loop.**

```
late Animation<double> animation;
late AnimationController controller;
Tween<double> _rotationTween = Tween(begin: 0, end: 2);

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();

  controller = AnimationController(
    vsync: this,
    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
  );

  animation = _rotationTween.animate(controller)
    ..addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
    })
    ..addStatusListener((status) {
      if (status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
        controller.repeat();
      } else if (status == AnimationStatus.dismissed) {
        controller.forward();
      }
    });

  controller.forward();
}
```

**2. Then we need own canvas to draw arrows. Then you need to pass**

```
class ArrowPainter extends CustomPainter {
ArrowPainter();
@override
void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
  final paint = Paint()
    ..color = Colors.grey[300]!
    ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
    ..strokeWidth = 3;

  var halfWidth = size.width/2;
  var halfHeight = size.height/2;

  var path = Path();
  path.moveTo(halfWidth - 5, halfHeight-12);
  path.lineTo(halfWidth, halfHeight-7);
  path.lineTo(halfWidth + 5, halfHeight - 12);
  canvas.drawPath(path,paint);

  path = Path();
  path.moveTo(halfWidth - 7, halfHeight-7);
  path.lineTo(halfWidth, halfHeight);
  path.lineTo(halfWidth + 7, halfHeight - 7);
  canvas.drawPath(path,paint);

  path = Path();
  path.moveTo(halfWidth - 9, halfHeight - 2);
  path.lineTo(halfWidth, halfHeight+7);
  path.lineTo(halfWidth + 9, halfHeight - 2 );
  canvas.drawPath(path,paint);

}

@override
bool shouldRepaint(ArrowPainter oldDelegate) => false;
```

}

**3. Now we need to add the custom paint to draw this canvas**

```
 @override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return CustomPaint(
    size: Size(40, 40),
    painter: ArrowPainter(),
  );
}
```

This will give you something like this

[image: canvas arrows]

**4. Now we add the value param in our custom painter**

```
class ArrowPainter extends CustomPainter {
  final int value;
  ArrowPainter({required this.value});
```

and use this value to change arrow colors

```
var path = Path();
path.moveTo(halfWidth - 5, halfHeight-12);
path.lineTo(halfWidth, halfHeight-7);
path.lineTo(halfWidth + 5, halfHeight - 12);
canvas.drawPath(path,paint..color = (value< 33 ? Colors.green : Colors.green.shade100));

path = Path();
path.moveTo(halfWidth - 7, halfHeight-7);
path.lineTo(halfWidth, halfHeight);
path.lineTo(halfWidth + 7, halfHeight - 7);
canvas.drawPath(path,paint..color = (value> 33 && value<66 ? Colors.green : Colors.green.shade100));

path = Path();
path.moveTo(halfWidth - 9, halfHeight - 2);
path.lineTo(halfWidth, halfHeight+7);
path.lineTo(halfWidth + 9, halfHeight - 2 );
canvas.drawPath(path,paint..color = (value> 66 ? Colors.green : Colors.green.shade100));
```

and setup out shouldRepaint to reload when value changed

```
@override
bool shouldRepaint(ArrowPainter oldDelegate) => oldDelegate.value != value;
```

**5. One last this is passing our animation value to our painter**

```
return CustomPaint(
  size: Size(40, 40),
  painter: ArrowPainter(value: (controller.value * 100).toInt()),
);
```

**6. Lastly don't forgot to dispose the controller on stateful widget**

```
@override
void dispose() {
  controller.dispose();
  super.dispose();
}
```

Now running the app will give you animated arrows just like your video. Example images:

[image: animation 1]
[image: animation 2]
[image: animation 3]

[Runnig dartpad example](https://dartpad.dev/?id=ea524278b513216d260bbb393591e2d3)